# WPF Adding tasks to columns

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am new to WPF and am trying to make a todo list in WPF and cannot figure out how to add tasks in columns.
The first column will contain the task and other column must have a 'delete' button auto generated in it.
I don't understand how to add the tasks programatically. 
Here is the XAML

```
<Window x:Class="ToDoList.MainWindow"

        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"

        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

        Title="MainWindow" Height="416.932" Width="525" Background="#FF1B1A19">

    <Grid Margin="0,0,181,-49">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ColumnDefinition Width="155*"/>

            <ColumnDefinition Width="13*"/>

        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Content="Task:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="47" VerticalAlignment="Top" 

Width="57" FontSize="18" Foreground="#FFF7EFEF"/>

        <TextBox Name="userTask" Height="25" Margin="0,10,-24,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 

VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="298" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 

BorderThickness="2,1" KeyDown="userTask_KeyDown"/>

        <ListBox  Name="taskList"  Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Height="265" Margin="5,52,-157,0" 

VerticalAlignment="Top" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                <DataTemplate>

                    <Grid Margin="0,16">

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" Name="taskCol" />

                            <ColumnDefinition Width="25" Name="buttonCol" />

                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Name="testABC" />

                    </Grid>

                </DataTemplate>

            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

           </ListBox>

       <Button Name="addTask" Content="Add" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" 

Margin="91,10,-147,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="82" Click="Button_Click"/>

    </Grid>


</Window>
```

Comment: did my answer below answer your question? You have not provided any feedback or comment about it.

Comment: Yes it did
Thank you so much.
It was perfect :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [WPF binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx). So create a list and assign it to ListBox's `ItemsSource`. In order to get updates on UI when you modify your list during application execution - use `ObservableCollection`. In my example I just bind it to collection of strings.

Your ListBox part will look as follows (note `Text="{Binding}"` part - it does a binding to a string, if you bind to some object also use `Path` there and a property name):

```
        <ListBox  Name="taskList"  Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Height="265" Margin="5,52,-157,0" 
VerticalAlignment="Top" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="0,16">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" Name="taskCol" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="25" Name="buttonCol" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Name="testABC" Text="{Binding}" Grid.Column="0" />
                        <Button Content="[x]" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

And a codebehind for it:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;


namespace ToDoList
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        private ObservableCollection<string> _tasks;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _tasks = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            taskList.ItemsSource = _tasks;
        }
        private void userTask_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _tasks.Add(userTask.Text);
        }
    }
}
```